# Android 5.1 Notificatios

Tags: java, android

For school i just need to make a simple app that will notifiy me when i press the button.

I made up the class for the activity but the google docs are for android 8.0 oreo and not for my development version of android (5.1.1).

does anyone know how to send a notification (as i think i figured out how to make one)?

thanks,

Ewan

my class:

https://gist.github.com/Tebreca/f310b7d921caff04eaddc530521ce824

Comment: The docs are for any / all API level. You can choose which level you want to see.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you actually have a problem or are you just concerned that it will not work with Android 5.1? If the answer is the latter, why not try it and see? It is just a case of creating a `Notification` object and invoking `notify(int id, Notification notification)` on the `NotificationManager`.

Answer (score 1):

```
This will set you for life ;)
```

PendingIntent pIpanel=" you can do this :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, " : version : <=M ");

        //noinspection deprecation
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_subtext))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLights(Color.CYAN, 500, 1200)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pIpanel)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

        notification = builder.build();



    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N | Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, " : version : N| N1 - 24: 25 ");

        //noinspection deprecation
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_subtext))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLights(Color.CYAN, 500, 1200)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pIpanel)

                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

        notification = builder.build();


    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, " : version : >=O ");


        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel
                (NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        mChannel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.CYAN);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        NotificationChannelGroup mGroup = new NotificationChannelGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ID, NOTIFICATION_GROUP_NAME);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(mGroup);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder
                (context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_subtext))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pIpanel)

                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

        notification = builder.build();
    }

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```